# Python Pandas, how to find the number of entries in a sub-index in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have this data frame:

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNF6y.png)

Level 1 index is STNAME, level 2 index is CTYNAME

What is the best way to find the number of entries contained in each level 1 index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I know is to reset the index before performing a `groupby`. I have made a simple reproductible example below, it has to be adapted to your use case.

It should work but there is maybe a better solution. I will have a look.

```
# Creating test data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])

# Reset the index,
# group by the first level and count the number of second level
# nunique can also be used to get the number of unique values

df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)['B'].count()

# A
# 2    1
# 3    1
# 4    1
# 5    3
# 7    2
# 8    2
```

## Edit

Here is I think a better solution using the great `value_counts` method on the index.

```
df.reset_index(level=1).index.value_counts()

# 5    3
# 8    2
# 7    2
# 4    1
# 3    1
# 2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
census_df = census_df.set_index(['STNAME'])
#this sets all the indices according to STNAME with multiple occurences of each STNAME
census_df.index.value_counts().index[0]
# .index gives all the indices present multiple times
# .value_counts() returns a series with number of occurence of each index sorted from max -> low
#.index[0] gives the STNAME with max occurences = max no. of counties
```